# How to append text for value in key-value pair in a text file that has many such pairs

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a text file `keyvalue.txt` with contents:

```
one=abc
two=def
three=ghi
four=jkl
five=mno
six=pqr
```

Now, I want to append `xyz` to value of `three` that will become

```
three=ghixyz
```

The resulting file contents should be:

```
one=abc
two=def
three=ghixyz
four=jkl
five=mno
six=pqr
```

Is there any way to do this in shell scripting?

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways; *e.g.* with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^RELEASESTATUS=.*/&xyz/' keyvalue.txt
```

This looks for lines starting with `RELEASESTATUS=`, matching the full line (thanks to `.*`), and replaces those lines with the contents of the line (`&`) followed by `xyz`.

Comment: @Jathavedas you’re welcome. Please take the [tour], and if one of the answers works for you, accept it using the big checkmark. (Kusulananda’s answer is better than mine...)

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452589/116858), but slightly different in the way it's executed:

```
sed -i '/^RELEASESTATUS=/s/$/xyz/' keyvalue.txt
```

Instead of replacing the entire line with a copy of itself with some text added to the end, this first locates the correct line (the line that has `RELEASESTATUS=` at the very start) and then substitutes in the required text at the end of that line.

This uses the fact that the general form of the substitute command (`s`) in `sed` is

```
start,end s/pattern/replacement/flags
```

where `start` and `end` gives the range of lines that the command should be applied to, given as a start and end address (and "address" may be a line number or regular expression, or an offset).  When using a single address, the command is applied to that line only (or to the single lines matching a particular regular expression).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "=" }; $1 == "RELEASESTATUS" { $2 = $2"xyz"; }; 1' keyvalue.txt
```

And if you have `GNU awk 4.1.0` or later you can do it inplace:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "=" }; $1 == "RELEASESTATUS" { $2 = $2"xyz"; }; 1' keyvalue.txt
```

Comment: +1. If the appended text is not fixed I recommend to pass it as a variable to Awk to avoid escaping issues: `awk -v suffix='xyz' 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "=" }; $1 == "RELEASESTATUS" { $2 = $2 suffix; }; 1'`

Comment: Beware [using gawk -i inplace like that introduces a security vulnerability](/q/749645) unless you modify `$AWKPATH` not to include `.` or make sure you run that command from within a working directory where nobody could create a file called `inplace` or `inplace.awk`.